# Limit a local Linux user to accessing only their own servers (by UID)

Tags: iptables

I hope you can do that somehow with the `owner` iptables module…

On a single machine, if:

- `userA` starts a TCP `serverA` on (random) port `1111`
- `userB` starts a TCP `serverB` on (random) port `2222`

… how can I:

- disallow `userB` to connect to `serverA`, based only on the fact that the owner of `serverA` is **not** `userB` themselves, but some other user,
- and still allow `userB` to connect to `serverB`, because `userB` owns the process of `serverB`?

Comment: This can actually be done with some firewalls, but then you're looking at actual dedicated firewall hardware and software, and it's not cheap.

Comment: @JennyD I see… would you name some? Maybe in an answer, as that would probably be the best one.

Comment: I'm not a firewall expert, but I think both Cisco and Juniper have such solutions. A good google search could be "firewall user ACL". You could also check the sister site https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

TCP connections work with IP addresses and port numbers. It does not know anything about "users". So unless each user has a unique fixed IP address, there is no way to block user A from creating a TCP connection to server B. Why would you want to anyway? If the server hosts a website, make it request authentication. User B won't be able to login to the website on server A so there is no problem.

Comment: Ummm, there’s the `owner` module in `iptables`, so not entirely true.

Comment: That module is only useful on outbound connections. I consider it pointless trying to configure all possible servers with that module to limit access on user-level.

Answer (score 2):

The owner iptables extension has more limitations than you think. From the [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) man page:

> ### owner
>
> This module attempts to match various characteristics of the packet
>   creator, for locally generated packets. This match is only valid in
>   the OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains. Forwarded packets do not have any
>   socket associated with them.

- Only OUTPUT is restricted, so you must restrict outgoing connections.
- Not only `userB`, but *every* user you don't want to make a connection.
- On every host, because if `userB` made this connection from `serverC` there would be nothing stopping them.
- You also need to make exceptions if `userB` is going to have network access at all. So you still have to define your service in terms of a connection tuple like ports.
- Plus apparently [the owner extension has non intuitive behavior with group membership](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373703/unable-to-get-iptables-owner-module-gid-owner-to-work).

---

A better solution would be to use authentication in your network protocol.

If you must restrict arbitrary network access of a given user, consider writing SELinux policy similar to the boolean  `httpd_can_network_connect_db`.

Comment: I see… I wanted to do some marking based on `-m owner`, but if that only works for `OUTPUT`, then I won’t then be able to compare the mark and `INPUT` owner…